# Prevent java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread

Tags: multithreading, memory, jvm, out-of-memory

We are encountering OOM errors when our system is low in memory, but there are still some things like 2Go of free memory.

First I was suspecting a thread count limit so I made a little test that creates threads and varies the `-XX:ThreadStackSize`. The amount of memory dedicated to the stack size seems to affect the maximum of threads but I can't explain how.

example.

- by setting  `-XX:ThreadStackSize=2000k` it can create 11000 ( which
  seems to be a hard limit).
- `-XX:ThreadStackSize=2100k` = 11000    threads
- `-XX:ThreadStackSize=2200k` =  9000 threads
- `-XX:ThreadStackSize=2300k` =  4000 threads
- `-XX:ThreadStackSize=2400k` =     1 threads

it seems strange to be able to create just one thread of `2400ko` while there is still `2Go` of free memory.
And the process seems to use at it maximum `160Mo` or residual memory, but virtual memory can grow to `9To`.

I don't understand what is the limit, what is acceptable or not. 
It is a problem when we have to decide if we can add a JVM application on a server.

It seems `heap + perm + ThreadStackSize * threads` is not enougt.

Because add `1Go` application to a server that has `2Go` usable memory seems good at first glance.

Why I have out of memory before reaching the maximum memory and how do you calculate the amount of memory a JVM application need?

Comment: What do you mean with "2Go" or "9To"? Does ``o`` stand for ``Byte`` here?

Comment: Besides thread stack size there is a number of other factors that may limit thread count, e.g. `ulimit -u`, `kernel.pid_max` and `kernel.threads-max` sysctl.

Comment: @PhilippLudwig sorry I'm french and in France we used to say octect of Byte ( which is a lot less ambiguous than `b` or capital `B` so yes it mean `Byte`.
@apangin I'm ok with that but how theses other values are they affected by `threadStackSize`? For exemple if the limit is `kernel.threads-max` the maximum number of thread should not be affected while changing the `threadStackSize`, no ?

Comment: `ThreadStackSize` does not affect ulimit and sysctl limits. What I wanted to say is that you probably see `OutOfMemoryError` not because of thread stack size, but due to other limits. Try `strace -f -e trace=clone` to find the reason.